# how many rows in my table how way i can show using php

Tags: php, mysqli

```
<?php

function getnumberRows() {
    $db_conn = getConn();
    if( ! $db_conn) {
        return flase;
    }

    $sql    = "SELECT count(leads_ID) FROM table1";
    $result = $db_conn->query($sql);
    $db_conn->close();

    return $result;

} ?>

<?php $result = getnumberRows(); ?>
    <p><a href="agentHome.php">New Lead</a></p>
<?php while ( $rows = $result->fetch_assoc() ): ?>
    <p><a href="agentAllLeads.php">All leads <?php echo $rows; ?></a></p>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

I want to show how many records i have in All Leads Like All leads(5) when i will add another one it will be All leads(6) i want to do like that thing how way i can do it some one help me............

Comment: `return flase;`, misspelled there

Comment: i corrected it. but that is not the main issue i think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the case of `mysqli`, you are returning an instance of `mysqli_result`. You should fetch the result of the query with `mysqli_fetch_row`, for instance:

```
$sql = 'SELECT count(leads_ID) FROM table1';
$result = $db_conn->query($sql);
return $result ? mysqli_fetch_row($result)[0] : 0;
```

Also note that you shouldn't re-connect to the database on every function call. Whether use [persistent connections](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.persistconns.php), or make a wrapper class (a database abstraction layer) connecting to the database only when necessary (something like `if (!$this->connection) $this->connection = $this->connect();`) and disconnecting in the `__destruct` method, for example. With these considerations in mind, you should modify your function as follows:

```
function getnumberRows() {
    $db_conn = getConn();
    if (!$db_conn) {
        return 0;
    }

    $sql    = "SELECT count(leads_ID) FROM table1";
    $result = $db_conn->query($sql);

    // You should normally do this in a database abstraction layer
    // $db_conn->close();

    return $result ? mysqli_fetch_row($result)[0] : 0;
}

<p><a href="agentHome.php">New Lead</a></p>
<p><a href="agentAllLeads.php">All leads <?php echo getnumberRows(); ?></a></p>
```

Comment: basically i include the database connection in top section and create function call the the function also <?php $result = getnumberRows(); ?> how way now i can use it on HTML i don't understand that point. <?php while ( $rows = $result->fetch_assoc() ): ?>
    <p><a href="agentAllLeads.php">All leads <?php echo $rows;     ?></a></p>
<?php endwhile; ?> Problem is How to echo After All leads it will be like All leads(20) when i add another one it will be All leads(21); How can i do it if you help me form creating function and use it one html that will be good for me.

Comment: is it possible to add me  on skp. "razraz_dha"

Comment: @RazBiswas, since `getnumberRows()` returns the number of rows, simply `<?php echo getnumberRows(); ?>`. You don't need the loop (`while`)

Comment: try but not works it shows Catchable fatal error: Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to string is it possible to add me on skype. "razraz_dha" i am new in php so i didn't catch the point normally.